# How to repeatedly get data from a python flask server using ajax?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

As part of a larger program to create a webpage using flask to analyze user-uploaded files, I'm attempting to create a loading screen that displays what step of the analyzing process the user is waiting on. The analysis happens in a python program that looks something like this.

```py
stages = 0 #This is what stage we're on.

def analyzer():
  global stages
  stages += 1

  #First step of analyzing code...

  stages += 1

  #Second step of analyzing code...

  #etc etc, two more stages
  return analyzed_data

@app.route("/stage", methods = ["GET"])
def stage():
    global stages
    return stages
```

This all seems to work. Using print statements, I know that the global variable "stages" does get increased during the analyzer() function.

The javascript code to display the current stage looks like this.

```
var x = setInterval(function(task){ //All the instructions within should run once per second
  $.ajax
    url: "/stage",
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success:function (data){},
    failure:function (errMsg){}

    //data should equal current stage
    //print current stage to screen, so user knows what step we're on
}, 1000);
```

I've placed console.log statements around and viewed the console on the webpage, and it seems [the error I'm currently getting is that $ in $.ajax is not defined.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vspm9.png)  How can i rewrite this ajax function so it retrieves the global variable "stages" from the python program once per second?

Answer (score 0):

The `$` syntax is jQuery. Are you including/linking to it? If not, and you don't want to use it, you should probably use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). If you really want to use ajax without jQuery, ajax would probably work something like this:

```
// Creating Our XMLHttpRequest object 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Making our connection  
var url = "/stage";
xhr.open("GET", url, true);

// function execute after request is successful 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
}
// Sending our request 
xhr.send();
```